# Confusing box2d forces

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

[image]

Hello Friends.
This is my demo game screen-shoot. Here i am using three buttons. Right-bottom button is used for jump and left-bottom buttons used for move left and right.

I have some questions
1) should i use linearImpuls for jump body??
2) For move right and left which types of force i applied???

PLease tell me i am confusing to use linearImpuls, applyforce and linearVelocity.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For move left/right you can use velocity. When you need to stop your character, just set velocity to (0.f, 0.f). For jumps use impulse. If your b2World has gravity, it will calculate jump trajectory by itself.

Comment: Thanks for replay but when i am using velocity for movement left-right  and stop for set velocity to zero that time jump impuls can not working properly because movement of body is in update method and also stop method is in update and update method continuos update its velocity to zero so jump impuls can not working. Sorry for poor english

Comment: Don't see where is the problem. You set velocity, when uset touches button right/stop. You don't need to set it in your update method. When you need your character to jump, you apply linear impulse to it. It is also should not be in the update method. So, the only thing in update method will be calling step in your b2World

Comment: Thanks for reply but i have another issue can you help me?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244771/speed-increase-when-applyforce-and-linearimpuls-apply-both-using-in-game

Answer (score 1):

for jump you use LinerImpulse

```
b2Vec2 locationWorld;
 locationWorld = b2Vec2(0.0f,8.0f);
 double Force= _body->GetMass();
  _body->ApplyLinearImpulse(Force*locationWorld, _body->GetWorldCenter());
```

for move left also use it but `b2Vec2(5.0f,0.0f)`

Comment: Hii Nimmi madam i have new problem regarding iPhone application using twitter so can you help me??? This is my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385358/how-to-integrate-twitter-in-application