# Speed increase when ApplyForce and LinearImpuls apply both using in Game

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

[image: Demo example]

In my game i am using LinearImpuls for jump player body and ApplyForce for movement left-right  .But the problem is that when player jump at that time if movement occur then player speed so increases its just look like running on air.

So what to do to resolve this problem??

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm no expert, but have you tried checking if player is on the ground and reducing the force applied otherwise?

Comment: Thanks for reply as you say that normally player is on ground so the force applied on player is normal.My query is how to reduce speed on air??

Comment: As I understand, you just need to set linear velocity to zero before applying impulse to the body. Then your character will jump vertically

Comment: But when my player jump vertically and at that time player moves left or right that and it looks like running on air.I don't want to do that.I want both jump and move but like mario game.

Answer (score 0):

I think keeping a check by boolean variable in code that at one time only one action can be performed either jump or moving left and right will solve the problem until and unless it does not affect your required movement.

Comment: I want to do same like mario.Problem is when player jump and also move in air that time jump impuls and move force both add or multiply and speed increase suddenly.if you give me your mail id then i send you my demo project.Please help me

Comment: I am not sure that I can help you out or not but I can try your code.Mail me on "abhinav.sri1502@gmail.com".